# Is it possible to determine the number of terms in a multinomial expansion, if all terms are exponents of $x$?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-theorem, multinomial-theorem

> Is it possible to determine the number of terms in a multinomial expansion, if all terms are exponents of $x\ ?$. For example, number of terms in the expansion of $\left(1 + x^{2} + x^{4} + x^{5}\right)^{7}\ ?$.

Clearly, the formula $\displaystyle\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$ isn't valid as we don't have different $x_i's$, but the exponents of same variable.

The above was just an example, but I am looking for number of terms in the expansion
$$
\left(\,{x^{a_{1}} + x^{a_{2}} + \cdots + x^{a_{k}}}\,\right)^{n}
$$ where $a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_k$ are integers and $n$ is a positive integer.

I have seen a few posts related to this, but they work in specific cases for example, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3380253/how-to-find-number-of-distinct-terms-in-a-multinomial-expansion) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2671623/distinct-terms-in-multinomial-expansion).

Comment: If $a_i$ are in increasing order, then a clear upper bound is $n(a_k-a_1) +1$ and a lower bound is $k$.

Comment: We can assume *wlog* that exponents $a_k$ are nonnegative integers with the smallest one equal zero.  It looks to me similar to the [change making problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem), so likely it is difficult.

Comment: @Tavish: Can you elaborate a bit more, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: @hardmath: I anticipated that it is indeed a tough problem, else it would have been already asked on this site. Solving a specific case still might be an easy job.

Comment: @HarryPotter Assuming all the $a_i$ are distinct, the expansion will contain $x^{na_1} +x^{na_2} +\cdots +x^{na_k} $ plus other terms, so there are atleast $k$ terms. Further, the largest power in the expansion will be $x^{na_k}$ and the smallest, $x^{na_1}$, so even if all powers from $na_1$ to $na_2$ appear, there will be no more than $n(a_k-a_1)+1$ terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Application of the *[multinomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Theorem)* in the specific case gives
\begin{align*}
(1+x^2+x^4+x^5)^7=\sum_{q=0}^{35}\sum_{{0j_0+2j_2+4j_4+5j_5=q}\atop{{j_0+j_2+j_4+j_5=7}\atop{j_0,j_2,j_4,j_5\geq 0}}}
\binom{7}{j_0,j_2,j_4,j_5}x^q\tag{1}
\end{align*}
We observe the number of different powers of $x$ is the number of different $4$-tuples $(j_0,j_2,j_4,j_5)$ which fulfill the conditions
\begin{align*}
0j_0+2j_2+4j_4+5j_5&=q\qquad(0\leq q\leq 35)\\
j_0+j_2+j_4+j_5&=7\\
j_0,j_2,j_4,j_5&\geq 0
\end{align*}
In general we can wlog assume $a_1< a_2< \cdots< a_k$. We obtain
\begin{align*}
(x^{a_1}+x^{a_2}+\cdots+x^{a_k})^n
&=\sum_{q=0}^{n a_k}\sum_{{\sum_{r=1}^k r j_r=q}\atop{{\sum_{r=1}^k j_r=n}\atop{j_r\geq 0, 1\leq r\leq k}}}
\binom{n}{j_1,j_2,\ldots,j_k}x^q
\end{align*}

> As in the specific case above we observe the number of different powers of $x$ is the number of different $k$-tuples $(j_r)_{1\leq r\leq k}$ which fulfill the conditions
> \begin{align*}
> &\sum_{r=1}^k r j_r=q\qquad(0\leq q\leq na_k)\\
> &\sum_{r=1}^k j_r=n\tag{2}\\
> &j_r\geq 0\qquad\qquad\ (1\leq r\leq k)
> \end{align*}

As far as I know there is no simple solution to calculate the number of wanted $k$-tuples  fulfilling the conditions in (2).